# Warnings in .jar file creation

Tags: java, oracle, executable-jar

I am creating an application that manages everyday user passwords. All the data is entered into Oracle 11g database. Am almost there but while creating the .jar file I get these warnings:

[image]

Also,

[image]

Thought it might help.

Comment: You are zipping two JARs which have intersecting classes in OJDBC6 and OJDBC5.jar

Comment: I don't think that's the problem because before making a few changes(updating a record) I created a .jar which got exported without any warnings. Yes, with both OJDBC5 and OJDBC6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Oracle's Driver Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) page:

`ojdbc6.jar` contains "Classes for use with JDK 1.6." while

`ojdbc5.jar` contains "Classes for use with JDK 1.5.".

Both couldn't be needed,just whichever one is compatible with the oldest Java version you are targeting.

Comment: I removed ojdbc5.jar from the buildpath and that solved the problem. However, if I move my application to a different computer with ojdbc5.jar driver will my app still be able to connect to the Database ?

Comment: The class-path (found inside your manifest.mf or sometimes in whatever command you are using to execute the JAR) will determine which library is called.  In the case of two jars in one classpath containing the same classes I think the precedence goes with whatever JAR is specified first, which is why this is a warning and not an error, it's not a problem but the results might be unexpected or at the very least its unnecessary.

Comment: This is a big problem with XML parsers as well where the order that the JARs are loaded can change (or break) an application.  The upside is you have total control over so much of the Java Runtime Envrionment